# SDL_RenderBlended looks ugly compared to Photoshop

Tags: sdl, sdl-ttf

I use SDL_ttf and I render using the TTF_RenderText_Blended function. I use the HelveticaNeueLight font.

The rendered text in SDL looks ugly compared to the text in photoshop, even though it's the same font:

[image]

Clearly, the "M", the "t", the "y" and the "c" look wrong. How can I make my text look acceptable?

Comment: Disable smooth font or anti-aliasing in photoshop and you will get the same result.

Comment: I know, but that's the opposite of what I want to achieve. It looks terrible without the smooth antialiasing

Answer (score 1):

I think you should experiment with [TTF_SetFontHinting](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_26.html). It can give pretty good results when accompanied by antialiasing. If you don't know what font hinting is, here's [wikipedia for you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting).